# Loading up old IDE drive on SATA machine

Tags: hard-drive, sata, pata

I have an old IDE drive from my last machine. The drive officially died, but I never tossed it since it has some important data on it. I always hoped the day would come that I'd figure out how to boot it up again and try to get data off of it. But, I have a problem that comes before the fact that it's dead. it's an IDE drive and my new(er) machine has a SATA board.

What's the best way to get the new machine to see the old drive (assuming I can resurrect it)? I don't want to invest a lot of time and resources on a drive that may not open at all anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to boot off it or just access it?

Comment: just access it. I have a handful of irreplaceable files on there. If I could get in once, get those files and get out, I'd be a happy and grateful man. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They make IDE/SATA to USB adapters.  They are not the most reliable connections, but they may be enough for you to retrieve anything you need off of it.
[image]
You can find these for a fairly cheap price on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000J01I1G)